# Interpreting standard deviation and interquartile shift changes in regression

Tags: regression, interpretation

Just a very basic question. I see in papers people running a linear regression, and then interpreting their results as the changes in y given a one standard deviation change in x, or an interquartile shift in x. And they usually do this by multiplying their coefficients by the standard deviation in x, or calculating the change in x from the 3rd to 1st quartile, and multiplying that by the coefficient. Why exactly is this giving it that interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

Standard deviation and interquartile range are common measures of dispersion. One thing the papers could be doing is comparing two regressors, specifically how they would change the dependent variable $Y$, taking account of different regressors will often have different dispersions.

This technique in the papers you have read may be more common in econometrics or finance. There are other changes of regressor, such as a unit change or one percentage point change, that can be used to determine how this affects the dependent variable. The interpretability of different changes of regressor will depend on the regressor and model specification

Keep in mind these are models, it could be anywhere on a continuum of a good to poor representation of reality.
Even if the regression does reflect reality well, a change in one regressor is likely to effect another regressor (although this obviously only appies if there is more than one regressor in the model), so changes in one are unlikely to affect the independent variable as simply as multiplying the change (dispersion in your case) by its coefficient. Further, the coefficient is a statistic and as well as having a standard error its value will vary depending on what other regressors are present in the regression.